# React: Fetch API response (no response or stuck) timeout after 60 seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data by calling api. Everything is fine if response is successful or if response returns error code. What to do if in case response returns nothing or its stuck, then how to implement timeout, wait for response for 60 seconds and the timeout. Please help me how this can be achieved. If invokeFeesScreen and invokeSignatureScreen services are not returning any response after 60 sec, then close the current dialog and open timeout dialog       setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
...prevState,
showFeeLoading: false,
}));

```
                //show time out screen
                setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    showFeeTimeout: true,
                }));
```

```
import React from "react";
const ErrorCodes = [101, 103];

export const **invokeFeesScreen** = async (language) => {
  const url = getFeesScreenUrl() + '&timeout=30&noninteractive=false&lang=' + language;
  const headers = getHeaders();
  const { data } = await SendPostMessageToService({
    url: url,
    headers: headers
  });

let userData ='';
**if (data == null || data == 'undefined') {
        userData = {
            FeesScreenState: {
                response: null
            }
        };
    }**
  if (data?.Error) {
    userData = {
      FeesScreenState: {
       response: data.Error.Message
     }
   };
  }

if (data?.Error) {
    if (data !== null && data.Error !== null && data.Error.Code !== null && ErrorCodes.indexOf(data.Error.Code) > -1) {
        userData = {
            FeesScreenState: {
                response: data.Error.Code
            }
        };
    }
}

if(data?.Event){
  if (data !== null && data.Event !== null && data.Event.FieldName !== null) {
    userData = {
      FeesScreenState: {
        response: data.Event.FieldName
      }
    };
  }
}
  return userData;
}

export const **invokeSignatureScreen** = async (language) => {
  const url = getSignatureScreenUrl() + language;
  const headers = getHeaders();
  const { data } = await SendPostMessageToService({
    url: url,
    headers: headers
  });

  let userData ='';
**if (data == null || data == 'undefined') {
        userData = {
            SignatureScreenState: {
                response: null
            }
        };
    }**
  if (data?.Error) {
    userData = {
      SignatureScreenState: {
       response: data.Error.Message
     }
   };
  }

if (data?.Error) {
    if (data !== null && data.Error !== null && data.Error.Code !== null && ErrorCodes.indexOf(data.Error.Code) > -1) {
        userData = {
            SignatureScreenState: {
                response: data.Error.Code
            }
        };
    }
}

  if ( data?.SignatureData) {
    userData = {
      SignatureScreenState:  {
        response: data.SignatureData
      }
    };
  }

  return userData;
}
__________________
TestApp.js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { invokeFeesScreen, invokeSignatureScreen } from './Services'

export const Wrapper = React.forwardRef(({
  ...props
}, ref) => {
  const uDispatch = useDispatch();
  const [{ showLoading }, setFeeLoading] = useState(false);
  const [{ showFeeTimeout }, setFeeTimeout] = useState(false);
  const [{ showFee }, setFee] = useState(initialStateSetup);
  const ErrorCodes = [101, 103];
  const FeeResponse = useSelector(state => state.app.DataReducer);
  const [invokeSignatureOnly , setinvokeSignatureOnly] = useState(false);

const sendToFee = async () => {
            setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                showFeeLoading: true,
            }));

            let FeesScreenResponse = '';
            if (invokeSignatureOnly) {
                FeesScreenResponse = FeeResponse;
            } else {
                FeesScreenResponse = await invokeFeesScreen(language);
                uDispatch(types.updateData(FeesScreenResponse));
            }

if (FeesScreenResponse.FeesScreenState.response == null)
     {
         setPinPadLoading((prevState) => ({
             ...prevState,
             showPinPadLoading: true,
         }));
          setTimeout(() => {
             setPinPadLoading((prevState) => ({
                 ...prevState,
                 showPinPadLoading: false,
             }));

             //show time out screen
             setPinPadTimeout((prevState) => ({
                 ...prevState,
                 showPinPadTimeout: true,
             }));
          }, TimeOut); // 60 seconds
     }
            if (FeesScreenResponse.FeesScreenState.response == 'BTN_CONFIRM') {
                const SignatureResponse = await invokesSignatureScreen(language);
                uDispatch(types.updateData(SignatureResponse));
                setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    showFeeLoading: false,
                }));

                //timeout on signature screen
                if (SignatureResponse.SignatureScreenState.response === "Request timed out") {
                    setinvokeSignatureOnly(true);
                    setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showFeeLoading: false,
                    }));

                    //show time out screen
                    setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showFeeTimeout: true,
                    }));
               }

                if (ErrorCodes.indexOf(SignatureResponse.SignatureScreenState.response) > -1) {
                   setinvokeSignatureOnly(true);

                    //closed out loading screen
                    setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showFeeLoading: false,
                    }));

                    //show time out screen
                    setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showFeeTimeout: true,
                    }));
                }

                //showAcceptModal}, setAcceptModal

                 setAcceptModal((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showAcceptModal: true,
                    }))
                }
              }));
                }
            }

if (FeesScreenResponse.FeesScreenState.response === "Request timed out") {
     setinvokeSignatureOnly(false);
                //closed out loading screen
                setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    showFeeLoading: false,
                }));
                //show time out screen
                setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                   showFeeTimeout: true,
                }));
            }
 if (ErrorCodes.indexOf(FeesScreenResponse.FeesScreenState.response) > -1) {
setinvokeSignatureOnly(false);

 //closed out loading screen
setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
...prevState,
showFeeLoading: false,
}));

//show time out screen

                setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    showFeeTimeout: true,
                }));
         }

};

  const submitForm = async props => {
    const formState = props.formState.toJS()
    const { fields } = formState

    const emptyRequiredFields = Object.values(fields).filter(({ required, value }) => required && !value)

    let hasError = false

   //Send to Fee Loading page

   const sendFeeModalContent = () => {

     //open up the screen

     return (

       <Block>

         <Block layout={true}>

           Please wait for the customer to acknowledge.

         </Block>

         <Block className={styles.modalspinner} layout={true} vertical={true} center={true}>

             <Spinner />

          </Block>

       </Block>

     );

   };

    //time out fee modal

    const timeoutFeeModal = () => {

      return (

        <Block className={styles.modalbuttoncontainer}>

          <SecondaryButton

            style={{ marginRight: 16 + "px" }}

            onClick={() =>{

              setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({

                ...prevState,

                showFeeTimeout: false,

              }))

              setinvokeSignatureOnly(false)

            }

          }

          >

            Back

          </SecondaryButton>

          <PrimaryButton

            onClick={() => {

              setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({

                ...prevState,

                showFeeTimeout: false,

              }));

              sendToFee();

            }}

          >

            Try again

          </PrimaryButton>

        </Block>

      );

    };

 

const initialStateSetup = {

  showCancelWireModal: false,

  showFee: false,

  showAcceptModal: false,

  showMobileConsent : false,

};

 

const TestApp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  )

};

export default TestApp;
```