# React: Fetch API response (Not return or stuck), timeout after 50 seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data by calling api. Everything is fine if response is successful or if response returns error code. What to do if in case response returns nothing or its stuck, then how to implement timeout, wait for response for 50 seconds and then timeout. Please help me how this can be achieved. If invokeFeesScreen and invokeSignatureScreen services are not returning any response after 50 sec, then close the current dialog and open timeout dialog. How to do this in TestApp.js.
setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, showFeeLoading: false, }));

```
            //show time out screen
            setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                showFeeTimeout: true,
            }));
```

````
import React from "react";
const ErrorCodes = [101, 103];

export const **invokeFeesScreen** = async (language) => {
  const url = getFeesScreenUrl() + '&timeout=30&noninteractive=false&lang=' + language;
  const headers = getHeaders();
  const { data } = await SendPostMessageToService({
    url: url,
    headers: headers
  });

let userData ='';
**if (data == null || data == 'undefined') {
        userData = {
            FeesScreenState: {
                response: null
            }
        };
    }**
  if (data?.Error) {
    userData = {
      FeesScreenState: {
       response: data.Error.Message
     }
   };
  }

if (data?.Error) {
    if (data !== null && data.Error !== null && data.Error.Code !== null && ErrorCodes.indexOf(data.Error.Code) > -1) {
        userData = {
            FeesScreenState: {
                response: data.Error.Code
            }
        };
    }
}

if(data?.Event){
  if (data !== null && data.Event !== null && data.Event.FieldName !== null) {
    userData = {
      FeesScreenState: {
        response: data.Event.FieldName
      }
    };
  }
}
  return userData;
}

export const **invokeSignatureScreen** = async (language) => {
  const url = getSignatureScreenUrl() + language;
  const headers = getHeaders();
  const { data } = await SendPostMessageToService({
    url: url,
    headers: headers
  });

  let userData ='';
**if (data == null || data == 'undefined') {
        userData = {
            SignatureScreenState: {
                response: null
            }
        };
    }**
  if (data?.Error) {
    userData = {
      SignatureScreenState: {
       response: data.Error.Message
     }
   };
  }

if (data?.Error) {
    if (data !== null && data.Error !== null && data.Error.Code !== null && ErrorCodes.indexOf(data.Error.Code) > -1) {
        userData = {
            SignatureScreenState: {
                response: data.Error.Code
            }
        };
    }
}

  if ( data?.SignatureData) {
    userData = {
      SignatureScreenState:  {
        response: data.SignatureData
      }
    };
  }

  return userData;
}
__________________
TestApp.js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { invokeFeesScreen, invokeSignatureScreen } from './Services'

export const Wrapper = React.forwardRef(({
  ...props
}, ref) => {
  const uDispatch = useDispatch();
  const [{ showLoading }, setFeeLoading] = useState(false);
  const [{ showFeeTimeout }, setFeeTimeout] = useState(false);
  const [{ showFee }, setFee] = useState(initialStateSetup);
  const ErrorCodes = [101, 103];
  const FeeResponse = useSelector(state => state.app.DataReducer);
  const [invokeSignatureOnly , setinvokeSignatureOnly] = useState(false);

const sendToFee = async () => {
            **setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                showFeeLoading: true,
            }));
setTimeout(() => {
             setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                 ...prevState,
                 showFeeLoading: false,
             }));
             //show time out screen
             setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                 ...prevState,
                 showFeeTimeout: true,
             }));
          }, 50000); // 50 seconds**

            let FeesScreenResponse = '';
            if (invokeSignatureOnly) {
                FeesScreenResponse = FeeResponse;
            } else {
                FeesScreenResponse = await invokeFeesScreen(language);
                uDispatch(types.updateData(FeesScreenResponse));
            }


            if (FeesScreenResponse.FeesScreenState.response == 'BTN_CONFIRM') {
                const SignatureResponse = await invokesSignatureScreen(language);
                uDispatch(types.updateData(SignatureResponse));
                setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    showFeeLoading: false,
                }));

                //timeout on signature screen
                if (SignatureResponse.SignatureScreenState.response === "Request timed out") {
                    setinvokeSignatureOnly(true);
                    setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showFeeLoading: false,
                    }));

                    //show time out screen
                    setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showFeeTimeout: true,
                    }));
               }

                if (ErrorCodes.indexOf(SignatureResponse.SignatureScreenState.response) > -1) {
                   setinvokeSignatureOnly(true);

                    //closed out loading screen
                    setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showFeeLoading: false,
                    }));

                    //show time out screen
                    setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showFeeTimeout: true,
                    }));
                }

                //showAcceptModal}, setAcceptModal

                 setAcceptModal((prevState) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showAcceptModal: true,
                    }))
                }
              }));
                }
            }

if (FeesScreenResponse.FeesScreenState.response === "Request timed out") {
     setinvokeSignatureOnly(false);
                //closed out loading screen
                setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    showFeeLoading: false,
                }));
                //show time out screen
                setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                   showFeeTimeout: true,
                }));
            }
 if (ErrorCodes.indexOf(FeesScreenResponse.FeesScreenState.response) > -1) {
setinvokeSignatureOnly(false);

 //closed out loading screen
setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
...prevState,
showFeeLoading: false,
}));

//show time out screen

                setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    showFeeTimeout: true,
                }));
         }

};

  const submitForm = async props => {
    const formState = props.formState.toJS()
    const { fields } = formState

    const emptyRequiredFields = Object.values(fields).filter(({ required, value }) => required && !value)

    let hasError = false

   //Send to Fee Loading page

   const sendFeeModalContent = () => {

     //open up the screen

     return (

       <Block>

         <Block layout={true}>

           Please wait for the customer to acknowledge.

         </Block>

         <Block className={styles.modalspinner} layout={true} vertical={true} center={true}>

             <Spinner />

          </Block>

       </Block>

     );

   };

    //time out fee modal

    const timeoutFeeModal = () => {

      return (

        <Block className={styles.modalbuttoncontainer}>

          <SecondaryButton

            style={{ marginRight: 16 + "px" }}

            onClick={() =>{

              setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({

                ...prevState,

                showFeeTimeout: false,

              }))

              setinvokeSignatureOnly(false)

            }

          }

          >

            Back

          </SecondaryButton>

          <PrimaryButton

            onClick={() => {

              setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({

                ...prevState,

                showFeeTimeout: false,

              }));

              sendToFee();

            }}

          >

            Try again

          </PrimaryButton>

        </Block>

      );

    };

 

const initialStateSetup = {

  showCancelWireModal: false,

  showFee: false,

  showAcceptModal: false,

  showMobileConsent : false,

};

 

const TestApp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  )

};

export default TestApp;```
````

Comment: Have you tried using debugger?

Comment: I used debugger to pause the response. Response is stuck. I am nost sure if this is correct or not   **setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                ...prevState,
                showFeeLoading: true,
            }));
setTimeout(() => {
             setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({
                 ...prevState,
                 showFeeLoading: false,
             }));
             //show time out screen
             setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({
                 ...prevState,
                 showFeeTimeout: true,
             }));
          }, 50000); // 50 seconds**

Comment: Initially dialog open having the spinner. Timer starts as soon as the dialog opens. If response wont come then it will timeout.

Comment: Please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074606/react-fetch-api-request-timeout-after-15-seconds?noredirect=1#comment135874469_77074606

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Fetch API response (no response or stuck) timeout after 60 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77048219/react-fetch-api-response-no-response-or-stuck-timeout-after-60-seconds)